# Stored Procedure not updating database asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

**Here is the Stored Procedure in the database.**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Taskedb_Insert
(

    @nNewID int output,
    @sFromEmail varchar(200)  = NULL,
    @sToEmail varchar(200)  = NULL,
    @sEmailSubject varchar(400)  = NULL,
    @sEmailBody varchar(MAX)  = NULL,
    @dEmailDate datetime  = NULL
)   
AS
 BEGIN

INSERT INTO [Taskedb]
(

    FromEmail, 
    ToEmail, 
    EmailSubject, 
    EmailBody, 
    EmailDate
) VALUES (

    @sFromEmail,
    @sToEmail,
    @sEmailSubject,
    @sEmailBody,
    @dEmailDate
)
SELECT @nNewID = @@IDENTITY
END
```

And This is the code in ASP.NET C#

```
string connectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=tbd_email_tasks;Integrated Security=True";

SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

connection.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Taskedb_Insert", connection);
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

SqlParameter p1 = cmd.Parameters.Add("@nNewID", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
p1.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;

SqlParameter p2 = cmd.Parameters.Add("@sEmailSubject", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar);
p2.Value = subject;

SqlParameter p3 = cmd.Parameters.Add("@sEmailBody", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar);
p3.Value = body;

SqlParameter p4 = cmd.Parameters.Add("@sToEmail", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar);
p4.Value = to;

SqlParameter p5 = cmd.Parameters.Add("@sFromEmail", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar);
p5.Value = from;

SqlParameter p6 = cmd.Parameters.Add("@dEmailDate", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime);
p6.Value = date;

//connection.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

It is not updating database. Please help me.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: @PareshJ I am not getting any error but this code is not saving anything to database.

Comment: You should consider using SCOPE_IDENTITY instead. Not sure why you defaulted all your parameters to NULL, you are passing values. Also, I would very strongly recommend you break the habit of prefixing variables with the datatype. What happens when you need to change the datatype? You either have to update every line of code or you have invalid prefixes.

Comment: For the issue at hand, is your procedure running? Is there a trigger on that table that might be squelching the error? Have you checked to see if the value for IDENT_CURRENT changes?

Comment: When I debug and on execution of cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() I got this error -->"String or binary data would be truncated.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."

Comment: @SeanLange in sql server management studio, my procedure is running but i am unable to execute it from my .net application.

Comment: Well look at your error message. You are passing a value to one of those columns that is longer than the datatype of the column. It can be a pain to deal with this error but your variable datatypes should match the columns in the table.

Comment: @SeanLange Yeah man you are right. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all for the help

I was getting this error because my table Taskedb had

nvarchar(50)

but I was injecting 67 character strength, which resulted in this error. Changing it to

nvarchar(MAX)

Problem Fixed

Answer (score 0):

You could check if it's probably in a transaction scope or such some . And of course I'd wrap your db connection and command in using block.